# after upgrading to 2.0+ v-calendar datepicker is always open (on load)

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vcalendar

after upgrading v-calendar (https://vcalendar.io/) all my datepickers are "open".

```
    <v-date-picker
    v-model='range1Start'
    :min-date='minDate'
    :max-date='maxDate'
    :popover="{ visibility: 'click' }"
    :input-props='{ class: "form-control form-control-sm"}'
    />
```

what am i missing?

br
T

Comment: did you get this figured out? I spent a few hours trying to get it and ended up reverting back to version 1... Not ideal, but at least it works.